# How to group articles by month in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

How to get articles grouped by month, like this:
1. January
article 1
article 2
2. February
article 3 
article 4
...

without hardcoding default joomla components and modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a category for each month, and then put the articles in corresponding category.

```
-Category YEAR
--Category January
---Article 1
---Article 2
--Category Ferbuary
---Article 1
---Article 2
```

...and so on

Or

You could manually set the creation date for the articles (if you dont need to show the real creation date), and then sort the articles by date created.

Answer (score 1):

You can put all your articles in a single category, add an "Articles Category" module, and then configure the grouping option to month.

See screenshot:

[image: joomla date grouping]

Answer (score 0):

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-structured-lists/10731

check this extension it shows articles grouped by year and month(presented in a hierarchy)

Comment: Looks like the download link is gone, but the code is still here: https://github.com/JoniJnm/mod_lca